# Is there a linear-time algorithm for max flow on dags

Tags: ds.algorithms, directed-acyclic-graph, max-flow

What is the fastest known algorithm for max flow on dags?
Can there be a linear-time algorithm running in time $O(|V|+|E|)$?

**Input**: a weighted dag $G=(V,E,w)$ where 
$E$ is given as an edge list $E$ and
$w$ is the edge weight function; and
two vertices $s$ and $t$.

**Output**: a max flow from $s$ to $t$.

The dag is simple (no loops, no parallel edges). 
Edge weights are positive integers.

Comment: Bipartite matching can be reduced to max-flow on a DAG(in linear time). So unless bipartite matching have a linear time solution, there is no linear time algorithm for max-flow on DAGs.

Comment: @ChaoXu convert you comment to an answer?

Comment: I understand now. Taking the wiki graph example, I can see for a particular case why a linear time algorithm won't work.